# Can 'were' be used as a conjunction to mean 'if'?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> **Were it true**, he would find himself in trouble.

In the sentence above, is it correct to say that 'were' is a conjunction or acting as such? I have seen writers use this construction to mean this:

> **If it were true**, he would find himself in trouble.

If it isn't a conjunction, what classification would this fall into?

Comment: It's a verb! Certain auxiliary verbs, most often *should, had* and the word *were* (a form of the verb *BE*), can occur before the subject in a conditional sentence. This has exactly the same meaning as using the word *if*. So *Had he replied, ...* means exactly the same as *If he had replied*; *Should he reply, ...* means the same as *If he should reply* and *Were he to reply, ...* means the same as *If he were to reply, ...*. The three auxiliary verbs *had, should* and *were* are still verbs in each of those examples.

Answer (score 1):

the word "were" is a form of the verb "to be" specifically the third-person past form. It is also frequently used in subjunctive constructs. It is not a a conjunction, nor is it functioning as one here..

> Were it true, he would find himself in trouble.

Is a somewhat literary or old-fashioned usage. It is not incorrect, but it would be seen as odd in many uses. It oes mean much the same as "If it were true that". Since this is discussing a possibility, it is a subjunctive form, and so "were" is appropriate.

Comment: Naively, it looks like a conjunction to me since it acts to conjoin the two clauses the same way "if" does. If "were" is not a subordinating conjunction, what causes the subordination? Is it the subject-auxiliary inversion itself? What conjoins the two clauses, preventing them from being a comma splice?

Comment: It's an omitted *if* to place more emphasis on the main clause.

Answer (score 0):

If is a logical statement. If A=B then C.

Were, in this usage, is a speculation. It is saying what you would do in an alternate situation to the normal or expected one.

"If the red light appears, call the manager" - this implies it is an expected outcome and if it happens, call the manager.

"Were the red light to appear, you should call the manager" - this implies it shouldn't appear, but if it did, then call the manager.

This is of course a very nuanced difference and nobody is going to call you out or be confused if you don't use them this way.

There is also "If I were" or "If it were" which is offering a choice in a hypothetical situation.

"If I get sick, I will see the doctor" - a logical conclusion

"If I were to get sick, I will see the doctor" - a response to a hypothetical situation